# how to push a view to another view 

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

How can I connect my button to another view controller class programmatically

here is code for my programmatically button

```
UIBarButtonItem *yearButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Year" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered    
 target:self action:@selector(year:)];


-(void) year:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Year button clicked");

    //I don't know what should I write here to connect my button to UIViewController**
    //when I added this line my process is terminated** 

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YearView" sender:self]; 
 }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"YearView"]){
       [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"YearView"];
    }
}
```

Here you can see my view in storyboard:
![enter image description here][1]

**Edit:**
**My process is Terminated when I used this method**

```
-(void)year:(id)sender{

// [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YearView" sender:self]; 
NSLog(@"Year button clicked");
YearView *yearVC = [[YearView alloc] initWithNibName:@"YearView" bundle:nil];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:yearVC animated:YES];   // [yearVC release];

}
```

Comment: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yearButton;

Comment: @RinjuJain where should I put it ? behind this -(void) year:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Year button clicked");  ???

Comment: if you want to add a button that you created programmatically to a `UIView` you can add with `addSubView`. but if the button is not showing on your `UIView` where it will show and what is the point to connect to another `ViewController`?

Comment: @nfarshchi I have my button but my problem is I don't know how should I connect my UIBarButton to the UIViewController programetically

Comment: I think in this case you just need to push `yearView` to your `navigationController`

Comment: Check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers this will help you..

Comment: @justin Just asking for code because you are new to Objective-C isn't a good way of using this site.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :

```
YearView *year = [[YearView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:year animated:YES];
```

It's good to read the tutorial first:
Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: @Terminator but with this code my buttons works and loaded the views

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *yearButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Year"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(year:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yearButton;

-(void) year:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Year button clicked");
    YearViewcontroller *yearVC = [[YearViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"YearViewcontroller" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController  pushViewController:yearVC  animated:YES];
    [yearVC release];
}
```

Comment: jain but what should I write inside of -(void) year:(id)sender{ my problem is how connect my button to UIViewController

Comment: Jain yes everything works but after NSLOg what should I write to connect my year button to yearview UIVIewController class as you can see in picture???

Comment: @justin you mean after you push year button you get navigated to `yearView`. it is different to connect to a `viewController`

Comment: thansk but I got error since I'm using storyboard should I have initWithNibName:@"YearViewcontroller" ?? @RinjuJain

Comment: Going through the trouble of loading and pushing a view manually when there is already a storyboard is wasted effort.

Comment: @Abizern yes but what is the problem here, I what to know it, how can I connect it manually

Comment: What is the segue identifier given in the storyboard that connects to the year view controller? Is that segue identifier the one connected to the year view controller or to the navigation controller of the year view controller?

Comment: @Terminator It's works thanks for reply the segue was year thanks

Answer (score 0):

To link your button with the method in the viewController, you need to set an IBOutlet in the interface designer (this is the simplest way). If you still want that in another view controller, you could set a property of the another viewController for example in the viewDidLoad method, so that the other viewController also has a reference to the button, altough that is far from ideal. Only one viewController should manage the button.

Comment: Thanks for reply would you please show me with code I'm really new to iOS